# How to normalize a r.v so that is has 3rd moment $1$?

Tags: normalization, skewness, moments

If we have a random variable having a certain distribution (assume its 3rd moment nonzero), we can *normalize* it so that it has zero mean and standard deviation $1$.

However, what if I wanted to have a random variable having the same distribution but having a 3rd moment as $1$. How should we "normalize" it in this case?